# Azure Application Insights new navigation behavior from dashboard

Tags: azure-application-insights, azureportal

During > 2 years, behavior of clicking on any application insights charts was to deep dive with chart filters.

below, clicking on exception (yellow bar) chart was going directly to out of the box expection filtered view, etc etc.
[image]

Since ~monday 10th september 2018, this behavior changed  (there was a ribbon but I can't find the message anymore) stating that appinsights "overview" panel is now the default one: in our situation, this page has no useful information because our appinsights instance is used for tracking logical events and not service performance.

[image]

as there was ribbon, I do suspect it's not a bug, is there any other way to recover the previous behavior, I suspect that I'm missing something.

Comment: not sure how to recover, but when you click on the chart like failure / server response, you should see the detail info.

Comment: that was the case until past week. here an animated gif of the new behavior. in the past I was getting pre-filtered details on this exact query.

https://otherappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/sharex/2018-09-17_13-36-20.gif

Comment: For the first pic, where is it in the portal? If you wanna get the events, you can click search button at the top of the overview panel.

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue! We're looking into it. The expectation is that this transition was supposed to work as before. The navigation to the Overview is a bug.

Comment: first pic is portal.azure.com entry with a dashboard including pinned appinsights charts.

Comment: Update: The fix is on its way to PROD. Should reach all stamps tomorrow.

Comment: now it's fixed on my appinsights instance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting a bug! The fix got deployed to PROD couple days ago. Please let us know if you still experience this issue.

Comment: as stated in comment of my initial message, it has been fixed :) thanks for the support & reactivity & quick deployment :o

Comment: sorry, didn't notice the last comment. thank you for confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a bug as per @ZakiMa mentioned in comments: `The expectation is that this transition was supposed to work as before. The navigation to the Overview is a bug.`

Comment: so happy to hear that it's a bug and not a feature (our experience for browsing event really went down) :) if not able to reproduce, I would be glad to spent time helping you.

Comment: can you please update your post with detailed steps to reproduce? thanks. I pinned the chart to dashboard, by clicking, not go to the overview page.

Comment: I'm lost :( I'm not even able (I can't find) to pin an appinsights chart ... back in time, I was using "Metrics explorer" panel to navigate within my events, narrowing them down, and pinned them to dasboard. If now I'm doing this from "Search", and if I pinned, I only have a "sumup" tile.
https://otherappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/sharex/2018-09-19_12-57-19_chrome.png

Comment: can you please attach some screenshots, like the whole application insights screen, the search screen etc. So when I'm back in company, I can compare with my portal.

Comment: @ZakiMa is referring that the fix is on it's way. Ivan do you still want extra screenshots ?